# Can I backup photos stored on parse.com?

Tags: parse-platform

We can export parse.com database data as JSON, but how can you export pictures stored there together with text data?
I was looking at the settings and couldn't find anything what would help with that.

Comment: What platform are you on, Windows, OSX?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do it automatically via an export button, however it is fairly easy to do manually.

You'll want to iterate through your table and pull down each item individually via the ParseFile interface.

Depending on what platform you are using, you could use the OSX or C# APIs. Or just go with using Python.